# How to tell if new GCP network or subnetwork resource is ready?

Tags: google-api-python-client, google-apis-explorer

I'm using the GCP API with Python 3 to make a new VPC network and subnetwork before making a GCE instance.  I make those 3 items in that order.  After creating the Network, I loop  a try/except block trying to make the subnetwork.  Without the loop, if I try to make a subnetwork too soon, I get an error like `"The resource 'projects/{my project}/global/networks/{my network}' is not ready"`.  Likewise, when I make the subnetwork, it returns a response right away, though the new subnet is not immediately ready.  I then loop a `compute.subnetworkds().get()` request much like before, but the responses are missing the [`state` field which is supposed to be present in the output per the docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/subnetworks/get).

My code looks like this

```
# Assume `compute` is set up and authenticated already, and assume `settings` object is declared with GCP_PROJECT
# defined.   

import time
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
region = 'us-west'

vpc_network_body = {
    "routingConfig": {
        "routingMode": "REGIONAL"
    },
    "autoCreateSubnetworks": False,
    "name": "my_network",
    "mtu": 1460
}

vpc_network_resp = compute.networks().insert(project=settings.GCP_PROJECT, body=vpc_network_body).execute()
vpc_network = vpc_network_resp['targetLink']

vcp_subnet_body = {
    "enableFlowLogs": False,
    'ipCidrRange': "10.0.0.0/24",
    "name": "my_subnet",
    "network": "my_network",
    "privateIpGoogleAccess": False,
    "region": f"{region}"
}

# Keep trying to create subnet until network is ready
while True:
    try:
        compute.subnetworks().insert(project=settings.GCP_PROJECT, region=region,
                                          body=vcp_subnet_body).execute()
        break
    except HttpError as e:
        print(f"VPC Network not ready.  Retrying subnet creation soon. {e}")
        time.sleep(3)

while True:
    try:
        
        subnetwork_resp = compute.subnetworks().get(project=settings.GCP_PROJECT, region=region,
                                                         subnetwork="my_subnet").execute()
        print(f"Subnetwork creation resp {subnetwork_resp}")
        # Ideally, this would work, but `state` isn't present
        if subnetwork_resp['state'] == 'READY':
            break
    except HttpError as e:
        print(f"Subnetwork not ready.  Checking again soon. {e}")
        time.sleep(3)
```

As noted in the comments, the last line in the `try` block of the last (3rd) `while` loop doesn't work since `state` is missing in the GCP API response.  My current solution is to try making an instance over and over until it succeeds, indicating the `subnetwork` is ready, but I think there must be a better way - what is it?

I try the same `subnetworks.get` API request using the API explorer (minutes later when the subnetwork is certainly ready) and get a response missing `state` too:

```
{
  "id": "129023512326123",
  "creationTimestamp": "2021-05-31T11:58:44.000-07:00",
  "name": "my_subnet",
  "network": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my_project/global/networks/my_network",
  "ipCidrRange": "10.0.0.0/29",
  "gatewayAddress": "10.0.0.1",
  "region": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my_project/regions/us-west1",
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my_project/regions/us-west1/subnetworks/my_subnet",
  "privateIpGoogleAccess": false,
  "fingerprint": "asdf",
  "enableFlowLogs": false,
  "privateIpv6GoogleAccess": "DISABLE_GOOGLE_ACCESS",
  "purpose": "PRIVATE",
  "logConfig": {
    "enable": false
  },
  "kind": "compute#subnetwork"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The state is not used for newly created subnetworks to indicate if they are done creating. From [the page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/subnetworks/get) for `subnetwork.get()`:

> **state**
>
> [Output Only] The state of the subnetwork, which can be one of the
> following values:
>
> READY: Subnetwork is created and ready to use
>
> DRAINING: only applicable to subnetworks that have the purpose set to
> INTERNAL_HTTPS_LOAD_BALANCER and indicates that connections to the
> load balancer are being drained. A subnetwork that is draining cannot
> be used or modified until it reaches a status of READY

This does not say that you can use it to determine if a subnetwork is done getting created.

---

However, you can get the status if you do another `subnetworks.insert()` using the exact same `requestId` and checking the `status` there, as described in the section [Query parameters](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/subnetworks/insert#query-parameters).

---

> **status**
>
> [Output Only] The status of the operation, which can be one of the
> following: PENDING, RUNNING, or DONE.

---

> **requestId**
>
> An optional request ID to identify requests. Specify a unique request
> ID so that if you must retry your request, the server will know to
> ignore the request if it has already been completed.
>
> For example, consider a situation where you make an initial request
> and the request times out. If you make the request again with the same
> request ID, the server can check if original operation with the same
> request ID was received, and if so, will ignore the second request.
> This prevents clients from accidentally creating duplicate
> commitments.
>
> The request ID must be a valid UUID with the exception that zero UUID
> is not supported (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000).